# Why servlet halt a moment in concurrent request

Tags: servlets, multithreading, concurrency

I use Axis for webservice service.
when more than  8 concurrent , there are  some request halt randomly for about 30 seconds.
I debug by log in every line and found  from my code:

```
public class foo{

    void bar(){
             a();
             log.debug('exit from a');
    }

    void a(){

             log.debug('exit a');
    }
```

the time between "exit a"  and "exit from a" are delay about 30 second.
This is no reason.

I try to increase web container thread pool , heap  but didn't help

==============
Enviroment websphere 6.1
Spring 2.5 , Hibernate 3 ,Axis 1.6.5
Min heap to 768
Max heap to 1024
Thread pool defult max to 300
Thread pool web container max to 500

===============

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark, but it happened to me once: Is there a chance that you perform **massive** logging, so the delays derive from the logger having to rotate or flush massive files?